# recurrence relation for loans

Tags: recurrence-relations

You borrow $4000$ dollars, at $12$ percentage compounded monthly, to
buy a car. If the loan is to be paid back over two years, what is the
monthly payment? Note you pay back same amount every month. Use a recurrence relation (for loans) to solve the problem.

What I have tried so far is
$P(A|P, i\%, N)$

This I substitute to $4 000(1\%, 24)$ and the table of discrete compounds give me $(A|P , 1\%,24) = 0.0471$

$4000(0.0471) = 188.4$
with $a_0 = 4 000$
and $a_n= a_{n-1} - 188.4$ gives $a_{24}= - 521.6$

However,  $4000 \times 1.12 = 4480 $ and $4480 \ne 521.6 $

The second thing i tried was to calculate with $a_{n-1}\times\left(1+\frac {0.12} {100}\right)-1666.6667$ and this gives $a_{24}= 61.115$

It should be $a_{24}= 0$, what am I missing?

Comment: This is an Amortization problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not gonna do your problem for you. However, here is a full explanation for the derivation of the formula for the monthly payment, and a more in-depth description can be found at my [blog post on this page.](http://franklin.dyer.me/entries/2017-3-30.html)

Given the initial balance, the number of payments, and the monthly interest amount, finding the monthly payment can be a tricky task. However, we can set up an iterated function to calculate it. First, we assign variables to the givens and the unknowns. Our givens are $L$, the loan amount; $m$, the monthly interest rate; and $n$, the number of payments. Our unknowns are $p$, the monthly payment; $i_k$, the interest amount at the *k*th payment; $l_k$ be the interest amount at the *k*th payment; and $B_k$, the balance after the *k*th payment.

We already know one thing about the relationship between $i_k$ and $B_k$; namely, that
$$i_k=mB_{k-1}$$

because the interest of the *k*th payment is the monthly interest times rate times the current balance before the payment is made. We also know that
$$l_k=p-i_k$$

because whatever part of a payment not interest is the principal part of the payment. Also, because whatever is not interest goes towards the loan,
$$B_k=B_{k-1}-l_k$$

We can now substitute $p-i_k$ for $l_k$ and we get
$$B_k=B_{k-1}-(p-i_k)$$
$$B_k=B_{k-1}-p+i_k$$

We also can substitute $mB_{k-1}$ for $i_k$, so
$$B_k=B_{k-1}-p+mB_{k-1}$$
$$B_k=(m+1)B_{k-1}-p$$

We have turned $B_k$ into a sequence. In order to finish defining the sequence, we need only one term of the sequence. We already know that before any payments, the balance is $L$, so we can let $B_0=L$. Then we can define $B_k$ as
$$B_k=f(B_{k-1})$$

where
$$f(x)=(m+1)x-p$$

However, since $B_0=L$, then
$$B_k=f^k(L)$$

and by our formula for the *n*th iteration of functions of the form $f(x)=cx+d$,
$$f_k(x)=(m+1)^kx+p\frac{1-(m+1)^k}{m}$$

and
$$B_k=(m+1)^kL+p\frac{1-(m+1)^k}{m}$$

But this is still in terms of $p$, which is an unknown as of yet. However, we can solve for $p$ because we know another value of $B_k$. Since, after the last payment, the balance will be $0$, we can say that $B_n=0$. We can substitute and solve for $p$:
$$0=(m+1)^nL+p\frac{1-(m+1)^n}{m}$$
$$p\frac{(m+1)^n-1}{m}=(m+1)^nL$$
$$p=\frac{m(m+1)^nL}{(m+1)^n-1}$$

Comment: For saying that you weren't going to do the whole problem, you sure seem to have done basically the whole problem

Comment: Ha! I meant that I wasn't going to do this specific case. It's easier just to generalize it.